# Download link to RDP file in IE9

Tags: http, download, internet-explorer-9, rdp

I have a website containing a link to an RDP file. When the user clicks the link, the file should be offered as a download. It works with every browser, also in IE9 on localhost. But online, IE9 does not recognize the file type and the file name, and clicking on save causes an  error. Did I forget a correct header? Or are there some trusted site settings I have to change since it works on localhost?

I get the following headers when accessing the rdp file:

```
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 12:58:50 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Demo_WIN.rdp"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 72
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=46
Connection: Keep-Alive

username:s:Tester431
full address:s:176.1.2.3
domain:s:MYRDP
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to set the content type to "application/rdp". Here are the relevant headers I use, which work on every browser I've tried, including IE9:

```
Content-Type: application/rdp; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Application.rdp
```

Comment: Sorry it took sometime until our next release! Thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly.